Permission denied problem
I need convert big xml document to csv file with XmlStarlet. Operation system - Ubuntu 22.04, source file  on usb-drive. When I try studying structure of XML document by command
xml el test.xml

I have error "Permission denied".
But command
cat test.xml

It works correctly.
permissions:
yrichs@yrichs-Vostro-5490:/media/yrichs/drive/tmp$ ll
итого 1830320
drwxrwxr-x  2 yrichs yrichs       4096 сен  9 20:06 ./
drwxrwx--- 10 yrichs yrichs       4096 сен  9 19:39 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 yrichs yrichs 1874231016 сен  9 19:55 test2.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 yrichs yrichs       2563 сен  9 13:53 test.xml
yrichs@yrichs-Vostro-5490:/media/yrichs/drive/tmp$ ll /media
итого 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 yrichs yrichs 4096 фев 20  2024 ./
drwxr-xr-x  22 root   root   4096 сен  6 15:30 ../
drwxr-x---+  3 yrichs yrichs 4096 сен  9 11:04 yrichs/
yrichs@yrichs-Vostro-5490:/media/yrichs/drive/tmp$ ll /media/yrichs
итого 12
drwxr-x---+  3 yrichs yrichs 4096 сен  9 11:04 ./
drwxr-xr-x   3 yrichs yrichs 4096 фев 20  2024 ../
drwxrwx---  10 yrichs yrichs 4096 сен  9 19:39 drive/
yrichs@yrichs-Vostro-5490:/media/yrichs/drive/tmp$ ll
итого 1830320
drwxrwxr-x  2 yrichs yrichs       4096 сен  9 20:06 ./
drwxrwx--- 10 yrichs yrichs       4096 сен  9 19:39 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 yrichs yrichs 1874231016 сен  9 19:55 test2.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 yrichs yrichs       2563 сен  9 13:53 test.xml
yrichs@yrichs-Vostro-5490:/media/yrichs/drive/tmp$ cat test.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HOUSETYPES>
    <HOUSETYPE ID="1" NAME="Владение" SHORTNAME="влд." DESC="Владение" ISACTIVE="false" UPDATEDATE="1900-01-01" STARTDATE="1900-01-01" ENDDATE="2015-11-05" />
</HOUSETYPES>

yrichs@yrichs-Vostro-5490:/media/yrichxml sel -T -t -m "//HOUSETYPES/HOUSETYPE" -v "@ID" -o ',' -v "@NAME" -o "," -v "@SHORTNAME" -n test.xml 
Permission denied: test.xml
Permission denied: test.xml
failed to load external entity "test.xml"

How to make it work?

Did you install xmlstarlet via apt, or as a snap? if the latter, the issue may be that the snap does not have the removable-media connection. See for example How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?

And sudo xml el test.xml doesn't help? Apologies if I'm not understanding the question

@steeldriver, thank you very much, your advice helped a lot, it was just that snap

This question is similar to: How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DavidDE I flagged it as a duplicate instead since there seem to be several good answers there and I don't know much about snaps
